# Rethrowing an Exception: Why does the method compile without a throws clause?

Tags: java

On the source code below I'm rethrowing an `Exception`.
Why is it not necessary to put the `throws` keyword on the method's signature?

```
public void throwsOrNotThrowsThatsTheQuestion() {
    try {

        // Any processing

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you can do that for a checked exception??

Comment: There seems to be a bug in Eclipse (Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20121004-1855) as its not showing any error in your exemple. IntelliJ shows expected behavior (Unhandled exception error). Maybe that's what you are seing

Comment: a good post about checked vs unchecked exceptions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation

Comment: you can even catch and rethrow `Throwable`. it's interesting that java7 is still not widely adopted and its features are not well known. but people would probably jump on java8 pretty fast.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This behavior appears to occur only on Java 1.7.  When compiling with 1.6, I get the following compiler error message:

```
c:\dev\src\misc>javac -source 1.6 Main.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
Main.java:22: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared
to be thrown
        throw e;
        ^
1 error
1 warning
```

But with Java 1.7, it compiles.

```
c:\dev\src\misc>javac -source 1.7 Main.java

c:\dev\src\misc>
```

... Until I actually throw an `Exception` in the `try` block:

```
public static void throwsOrNotThrowsThatsTheQuestion() {
try {

    // Any processing
    throw new IOException("Fake!");

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

Compiling...

```
c:\dev\src\misc>javac -source 1.7 Main.java
Main.java:22: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declare
d to be thrown
        throw e;
        ^
1 error
```

It looks like Java 1.7 got smart enough to detect the kind of `Exception`(s) that might be thrown by analyzing the `try` block code, where as 1.6 just saw `throw e;` of type `Exception` and gave an error just for that.

Changing it to throw a `RuntimeException` made it compile as expected, because as always, unchecked `Exception`s don't need a `throws` clause:

```
public static void throwsOrNotThrowsThatsTheQuestion() {
try {

    // Any processing
    throw new RuntimeException("Fake!");

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

Compiling...

```
c:\dev\src\misc>javac -source 1.7 Main.java

c:\dev\src\misc>
```

**The Explanation**

Here's what's going on:

Java 7 introduced [more inclusive type checking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html#rethrow).  Quoting...

> Consider the following example:

```
static class FirstException extends Exception { }
static class SecondException extends Exception { }

public void rethrowException(String exceptionName) throws Exception {
  try {
    if (exceptionName.equals("First")) {
      throw new FirstException();
    } else {
      throw new SecondException();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

> This examples's try block could throw either FirstException or SecondException. Suppose you want to specify these exception types in the throws clause of the rethrowException method declaration. In releases prior to Java SE 7, you cannot do so. Because the exception parameter of the catch clause, e, is type Exception, and the catch block rethrows the exception parameter e, you can only specify the exception type Exception in the throws clause of the rethrowException method declaration.
>
> However, **in Java SE 7, you can specify the exception types FirstException and SecondException in the throws clause in the rethrowException method declaration**. The Java SE 7 compiler can determine that the exception thrown by the statement throw e must have come from the try block, and the only exceptions thrown by the try block can be FirstException and SecondException. Even though the exception parameter of the catch clause, e, is type Exception, the compiler can determine that it is an instance of either FirstException or SecondException:

(emphasis mine)

```
public void rethrowException(String exceptionName)
throws FirstException, SecondException {
  try {
    // ...
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Comment: I wonder... is this related to the fact that Java 7 introduced multicatch statements? So that it's smart enough to interpret it as `catch (FirstException | SecondException e)` ?

Answer (score 5):

java.lang.Exception is a checked exception so this won't work or even compile. It would work with a unckeched (java.lang.RuntimeException).
It makes absolutly no difference whether you throw an exception inside a catch block or not.

The compiler error would look something like this (depending on the compiler):

> java: unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown

EDIT: Java 7 can deal with such situations if you never actually throw the exception

Comment: I try with java 7 and actually compiles.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is not necessary to put the throws keyword on the method's
>   signature?

You can put that  cause your `// Any processing` is not throwing any *checked-exception*.

Example:

This compile fine.

```
public void throwsOrNotThrowsThatsTheQuestion() {
    try {

        throw new RuntimeException();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
```

This won't compile, you need to add `throws` clause.

```
public void throwsOrNotThrowsThatsTheQuestion() {
    try {
        throw new Exception();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //do something like log and rethrow
        throw e;
    }
}
```

**This is working since java 7.** In previous version an exception is thrown. More information [rethrow in java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html#rethrow)

Comment: Yep, with Java 7, i try in netbeans, i was surprised when i discover this 3 months ago, i don't know if in previous version this work, i thought the same as you @hgoebl

Comment: best answer of the stack from far

Comment: OK, I trust you. Java is getting more intelligent!

Comment: @nachokk Same code is throwing an exception JAVA 6 :-)., looks like something has changed in JAVA 7. Very much surprising. http://www.mindview.net/Etc/Discussions/CheckedExceptions

Comment: @SathishJayapal yep, this feature is since java7

Answer (score -1):

When you use throws with a method, it means that the statement which will call that method must be surrounded with a try catch block.

But if the method already includes try catch block then no thorws declaration is needed as the exception being thrown by the method is being handled there only.

The statement calling this method does not need a to be surrounded with try catch block.

Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: The exception is not "being handled there only", because it _rethrows_ it.

Comment: I think you mis read what I said @ajb. Please go through it again and understand each word which I have written. Then make a decision.

Comment: OK, I did.  My decision is that what you wrote is pretty vague--when you use the word "method", I don't know whether you mean the method in the post, a method called by that method, or a method that calls the method.  Anyway, we've already determined that `throwsOrNotThrowsThatsTheQuestion` may or may not need a `throws` declaration depending on what's in the "Any processing" code.

Comment: By your words, it seems like you understood what I meant and what is included in the post. I just needed the same. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

> throw new `Exception();` is something you should never do in a catch
>   block, but you may have to or want to do `throw new
>   SomeException(throwable);` (preserving the full stack trace) instead
>   of throw `throwable;` in order to conform to the API of your method,
>   e.g. when it declares to throw `SomeException` but you're calling code
>   that might throw an `IOException` that you don't want to add to you
>   method's throws clause.
>
> The probably most common case is new RuntimeException(throwable); to
>   avoid having a throws clause altogether.