# Unexpected exception handling during compilation

Tags: java, exception

I encountered the following method, which to my surprise compiled just fine:

```
private String getControlMessageBlocking() throws ProtocolException,
        InterruptedException, IOException {
    try {
        // <Code that may throw any of the three listed exceptions>
        return controlMessage;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }

}
```

Why isn't it necessary for the `Exception` to be caught?

Comment: What do you think is wrong here?

Comment: The fact that any type of exception might be thrown by the catch block.

Comment: What code is there before the `return` statement in the `try` block, and what exceptions can this code code throw?

Comment: I actually think this is a good question - only 3 explicit exceptions are allowed to be thrown, but the code here is potentially throwing a different (unlisted) type. Nandkumar's answer for why this behavior is allowed is correct.

Comment: You forgot to add the jdk version.

Comment: Check the difference of checked and unchecked exceptions.

Comment: Is this really valid? I get an exception because of `throw e` because the method does not `throws Exception`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Which JDK version are you using? This is only allowed in JDK 7 and higher.

Comment: @CraigOtis Actually no, I was using Java 6 without knowing it. I learned something new today. Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Rethrowing an Exception: Why does the method compile without a throws clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913834/rethrowing-an-exception-why-does-the-method-compile-without-a-throws-clause).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is the feature added in Java 7. Have a look at [Rethrowing Exceptions with More Inclusive Type Checking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html#rethrow)

Comment: i think that was possbile before java 7

Comment: From the link, "The Java SE 7 compiler performs more precise analysis of rethrown exceptions than earlier releases of Java SE"

Comment: @PhilippSander : oh really, then you should try it in earlier versions

Comment: @Tobold - I think it answers it pretty well

Comment: This looks like the answer, however OP didn't include the code before the `return` in the `try` block. If said code can throw these three exceptions, then yes it is valid.